# Fast & Accurate trimming of small parts from mp4 files

Tags: video, ffmpeg, trim

I am looking for a method to quickly trim around 2 frames from the edges of mp4 files.
Using ffmpeg I am able to do that with the following, however i'd like something faster:

```
ffmpeg -y -i myVid.mp4 -ss 0.066 -t 0.066 -c:a copy result.mp4
```

This works because i'm using the relatively slow seeking [put ss after the file name] option and encode. I have to encode (per ffmpeg devs) because i'm trimming less than GOP time (my vids GOP is 33 frames).

Now i want to make this faster. seems awful that i have to encode the whole vid for this small trimming.

My question is is there a good method to do that faster, and what possible caveats exist with this proposed solution [that i know that doesn't 100%  work]:

1. Segment the file to 3 parts, using the segment muxer, using segment_times to ask for relatively small begin and end. this should create 3 segments.
2. trim using -ss from the first segment. trim using -t the last segment (after figuring out its duration). both are done using encoding of video frames (i'm using a default, just noting -c:a copy).
3. concat them back through concat demuxer, with streams copy.

trying this than on some players the middle part is simply skipped. so i guess something is wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand how video codecs work. You cant just cut out first frame and hope that everything will be all right. First frame is I-frame and you have to decode and and encode GOP anyway.

As for the rest mp4 file, it has metadata (moov atom) that also should be modified after you change video data, and it's usually at the end of file. Changing container probably can solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks @ptQa. I might have to explain a little further. Step #1 is done with the segment muxer. as far as my understanding goes it makes sure to segment at key frames. Step #2 trims and encodes the first and final segments. i'm not just cutting the first frame. This re-encoding should take care of having the first and final segment with keyframe as well.  So as far as key frames are involved I do not expect issues. 
    RE container, any recommendations that you can make to something that will allow this sort of procedure? or any faster trimming?

Comment: Well, it's not proper way, but you can try to use mpegts format and after that just use "cat" to join all segments except first one and last one